# why do both lyft and uber mobile web api's require latitude/longitude for destination

Tags: uber-api, lyft-api

I have a mobile standalone web app. The app stores destination (aka dropoff) addresses for the user but getting lat/lon for those address is not only not easy but also hard to do at runtime. However, for both lyft and Uber, it is not enough to pass just the address in the dropoff. Apparently you also have to include the lat/lon query parms. It seems silly that I am calling a native app from my app (either uber or lyft), both of which allow the user to manually type in a dropoff address, yet it will not let my app pass in just the dropoff address and calculate the lat/lon internally as it does when a user manually types in the address.

anyway around this programmatically?

Comment: The dropoff address is URL encoded before I call their native mobile apps so that is not the issue.

Comment: my app creates a mobile speed dial for a person or venue. Each instance of the app also allows the user to create their own speed dial that they in turn can share with others. By speed dial I don't just mean phone. It also means location (user can get google map directions, uber or lyft). But most people don't inherently know their GPS coordinates. They do know their address. So my app has to not only store the address but also geocode the location and store that on my server (for when the speed dial is shared). This would not be required if I could simply send the address to uber/lyft.

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation, but I'd imagine:

1. They don't want people using their APIs to geocode addresses
2. The address resolution is something most apps can achieve using other sources
3. Lat/Long is wholly unambiguous, whereas an address could have all manner of spelling / formatting issues for the API to have to resolve, increasing demand through subsequent requests.

The [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html) seem to indicate that geocoding is entirely possible natively, so it's just a little more work.

**tl;dr**

Uber/Lyft don't want their API abused for geocoding, and most platforms have a way of resolving an address into a lat/long pair, which provides exactness for the API to work with.

Comment: 1. I am calling their native app and passing a dropoff address. Your answer would make sense if I was using their app to geocode addresses and then somehow magically derived the result (after my app already relinquished control to them) but that is not the case here. So sorry but this reason is not logical. 2. yes but why solve the same problem twice? The native app already does it and has to do it. This is evident in the fact that users manually type in destination addresses. 3. ya I get that Lat/Lon is unambiguous but not the point of this question. If they want me to direct traffic to them

Comment: "The Apple Docs seem to indicate that geocoding is entirely possible natively, so it's just a little more work."

I think you missed the very first line in my question...

"I have a mobile standalone web app." Which means it is NOT native.

Comment: @KerryDavis apologies, and indeed, if they returned out a lat/long pair for an address they could indeed be abused for geocoding. This is obviously trickier given you're using a standalone web app, but the API is the API, so I'd say just go with using a geocoding solution like google maps.